# EclipseLink permanent connection

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

I have a project that uses EclipseLink 2.1.3 under Tomcat 7.

What's bugging me is that the connection to the server doesn't persist through all of the app's life.
For a ServerSession to start I have to access the application manually.

Is there a way to automatically start a ServerSession when the application deploys and keep it running at all times ? So that I can access the application after a long idle time without having to wait ?

Thank you!

EDIT:
I have the following lines in persistence.xml

```
  <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.read-connections.min" value="5"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.read-connections.max" value="10"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.write-connections.min" value="6"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.write-connections.max" value="12"/>
```

Comment: What is a ServerSession? Are you talking about JDBC connections?

Comment: Yes, that's right. In the logfile it appears as a 'ServerSession' - 
[EL Info]: 2012-01-11 18:24:35.181--ServerSession(2672545)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.3.v20110304-r9073

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server applications usually use a JDBC connection pool to get connections and reuse them. Depending on the pool you use, you may configure it to keep a given number of connections open.

Comment: I already set up minimum connections on both read & write > 0 and still nothing..

Comment: And how do you diagnose that the server is busy opening a new connection when accessing the application after a long idle time? Maybe the JVM memory has just been swapped to disk, and it takes time to reload it into main memory. Anyway, in production, you shouldn't have much idle time anyway.

Comment: Actually, when I deploy the app to the server I leave it for ~10 mins.
Nothing happens, but when I access the app I can see that only then EclipseLink is logging into the Database server.
I can post the full persistence.xml fwiw

Comment: Maybe the session factory is only created when a servlet is initialized, and the servlet is not initialized until the first request is made. It all depends on how you webapp works and is configured.

Comment: I managed to fix it with your last comment, by creating my entitymanager on startup with something like
<bean id="onLoad" class="springapp.repository.OnLoad" lazy-init="false" init-method="onStartup"/>